# Benefits from using the uniform structure of compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness, uniform-spaces

It is well known that every compact Hausdorff space admits a unique (necessarily complete) uniform structure which is compatible with the topology, and every continuous function from such a space to a uniform space is uniformly continuous.

Are there situations in the general theory of compact Hausdorff spaces where it is beneficial to use the theory of uniform spaces? I can imagine, it might be helpful to prove the existence of certain points by using the convergence of arbitrary Cauchy filters/nets.

One direct application I can think of is, that for compact Hausdorff spaces $X,Y$ and a dense subset $A \subseteq X$ any uniformly continuous map $f : A \to Y$ (w.r.t. to the subspace uniformity on $A$) can be uniquely extended by continuity to a map $\overline{f} : X \to Y$. By characterizing the uniformly continuous maps from $A$ in terms of the topology on $X$ one may obtain an interesting (probably well known) extension result.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you for the suggestion! I forgot, that not every continuous map from $A$ must be uniformly continuous. Now the statement should be correct.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: Extendable to which space? A space which contains a proper dense compact Hausdorff subspace cannot be Hausdorff, so that situation seems quite rare.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: Yes, that might indeed be helpful. But for this statement we really need the terms of uniform spaces and uniformly continuous maps. I am looking for purely topological results about compact Hausdorff spaces, which can be derived from the theory of uniform spaces.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: This statement (which is new to me) is really nice - thank you! Does it become wrong for arbitrary spaces?

Answer (score 1):

**Divisibility**:

A compact Hausdorff space is much more than just uniformizible, it is [divisible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345448/is-every-t-4-topological-space-divisible). It's clear that divisibility has much to do with uniformizability. For example every T1 divisible space is uniformizable and so it is T2 and Tychonoff. It's clear how uniform spaces help.

**Minimal Uniformity**:

A Tychonov space is locally compact iff it allows a compactible minimal uniformity. (according to [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351016/is-a-minimal-hausdorff-uniformity-compact))

**Nets**:

If $X$ is a Tychonov space and every net on a dense $A⊆X$ has a convergent subnet, then $X$ is compact. The proof is straightforward in Uniform Space Theory.

There are other connections.